# Why would my WiFi connection be slow?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Linksys EA6300 (version 1) WiFi router with the latest firmware update. I've had it in service for about 8 months now, and it was fine pre- and post- firmware update, but for a couple of months or so now, I've had problems with WiFi connectivity from any of several laptops. If I plug the laptop into the network physically, (connecting to the same router), it works fine (no doubt the connectivity issue is associated with the WiFi link). Assuming the problem is interference, I tried switching from the default channels, but it hasn't made a noticeable difference. Rebooting/cycling power to the unit doesn't seem to have any effect (eliminating suspicion of creeping software glitches); sometimes the connection is OK, sometimes it's poor, reinforcing my suspicion that the problem is interference. The router is in an "electronics friendly" location (cool), and the signal strength indicator always shows good signal, even when the connection is slow or failing.

What could be the cause? Is it interference as I suspect? If so, is there anything else I can do about it besides switching channels? Would a different brand/type of router be more immune to interference? If not interference, what else could be causing the problem?

Comment: The description of the problem, is very vague. You say it's "slow", but how slow? And how are you measuring? When the connection is "OK", what does that mean? What do you measure then and how are you measuring? What precisely does "poor" mean?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's subjective. I often remote desktop from my laptop to another computer (which is on the wired portion) on my network. Under "normal" circumstances, it's hard to tell that it is a remote desktop experience - feels just I am working locally. But there are times where the remote desktop paints very slowly (several seconds to redraw the screen) or displays "reconnecting" messages.

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)